# Алгоритм равномерного распределения Хэша

Tags: ruby

необходимо вывести хэш с распределенными значениями ключей. Есть хэш

```
{5 => 6, 10 => 7, 20 => 8, 50 => 9, 100 => 1}
```

и на вход идет сумма

```
615 - amount
```

ключи это название денег (5 - пять рублей, 10 - десять рублей, 20 - двадцать рублей, 50 - пятьдесят рублей, 100 - стро рублей)
значения - это кол-во купюр. 
amount - требуемая сумма
нужен алгоритм который будет по кругу докладывать по одному значению(кол-во) каждого ключа ( каждого номинала 5, 10, 20 ... ) пока не наберётся нужная сумма.

вот что я сделал

```
   banknotes = {5 => 6, 10 => 7, 20 => 8, 50 => 9, 100 => 1}
   amount = 615

   def spreaded_alg( amount )
     min = banknotes.keys.min
     init_avg  = amount / banknotes.keys.sum 
      result   = banknotes.transform_values { init_avg } 
      delta    = amount - result.sum { |k, v| k * v }
      if delta > 0 
      loop do
        banknotes.keys.each do | val |
         if delta - val >= 0 and result[val] + 1 < banknotes[val]
          delta -= val
          result[val] += 1
         end
        end
       break if delta < min
     end
    end
   result
  end
```

но он выдает

```
 result = {100=>3, 50=>4, 20=>3, 10=>4, 5=>3}
```

он равномерно распределяет как надо, но у меня нету 100=>3,а есть только 100=>1

как тут это можно еще предусмотреть ?

Answer (score 1):

решил самостоятельно

```
  banknotes = {5 => 10, 10 => 10, 20 => 10, 50 => 10, 100 => 5}
  amount = 330



def spreaded_alg(amount)
validate_money!(amount: amount)
min = banknotes.keys.min
avg = amount / banknotes.keys.sum.round(0)
result = banknotes.transform_values {avg}
delta = amount - result.sum {|k, v| k * v}

 if delta > 0
  loop do
    banknotes.keys.each do |value|
      if delta - value >= 0 && result[value] > banknotes[value]
        delta += value # 160
        result[value] -= 1
      end
      if delta - value >= 0 && result[value] + 1 <= banknotes[value]
        delta -= value
        result[value] += 1
      end
    end
    break if delta < min
  end
end
result
end
```